# Sencha touch: How can I load a JSON result into an HTML panel?

Tags: html, json, sencha-touch, panel

I have been trying combinations of all I could think of and I also found nothing from searching, but what I'm trying to do is load a JSON object from my server and then use that to render a panel with a video, info, etc.

But I can't get anything to work though, what am I doing wrong here?

```
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
            navigationBar: {hidden: true},
        title: 'Video feed',

            html: '<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls"><source src="{video.url}" type="video/mp4"></video>',

        store: {
        autoLoad: true,
            fields: ['video'],
            proxy: { type: 'jsonp', url: 'http://patrick.includu.com/app/appvideos/getVideoPage/234', reader: { type: 'json' } }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that your JSON returning from your proxy is invalid. You can validate it [here](http://jsonlint.com/).

To render a view from your JSON take a look at [Sencha's Dataview](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/dataview). Here you use an `itemTpl` to render your video, info etc. So, in your case something like this:

```
itemTpl: '<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls"><source src="{video.url}" type="video/mp4"></video>'
```

I hope this helps you further!

Answer (score 0):

If your store is going to have more than one record of videos and you want to display all of them, then try removing `html:` and adding:

```
tpl: '<tpl for=".">' + 
       '<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls"><source src="{video.url}" type="video/mp4"></video>' +
     '</tpl>'
```

If you are just showing one video at a time just do: (still removing `html:` though)

```
tpl: '<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls"><source src="{video.url}" type="video/mp4"></video>'
```

Another gotcha: If a `html` tag is specified, even as `html: ''` it will always override the tpl specified.